# How do I block IP addresses in SuSEFirewall?

Tags: security, firewall, opensuse

Does SuSEfirewall in OpenSuSE 11 provide an easy way to block all traffic from a list of IP addresses? Ideally just a textfile into which I can put all IP addresses I want blocked, otherwise some configuration option. I've looked through /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2, but haven't been able to find anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just block IP, you can add the following line to the file /etc/hosts.allow

Code:

```
  ALL:    129.111.112.112 : deny
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to block ip1 you can edit  FW_MASQ_NETS as follows if that's not working just mail to me binynebi@yahoo.com

FW_MASQ_NETS="0.0.0.0/0,!ip1"